# How to set allow experimental window functions = 1 globally?

Tags: clickhouse

I want these window functions be allowed globally and not with every session or query. How do I set them up? I need them to be run in materialized views on background, is this yet working? I've set one materialized view with them and it is not filling up, but side "insert into" query with the allow flag =1 fills it. So it has to be allowed globally as I understand. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/allow_experimental_window_functions.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
   <profiles>
       <default>
           <allow_experimental_window_functions>1</allow_experimental_window_functions>
       </default>
   </profiles>
</yandex>
```

Comment: Hello Denny. Muchos graciac, amigo! :)